# AngularJS: Save data on before unload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, onbeforeunload

I'm using this event to save some data in localStorage when the user unload the page:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            saveSomeDataInLocalStorage();
            if($scope.message){
                return "You haven't sent your message yet. Do you want to leave without sending?";
            }
            else
                return null;
        };
```

When enters to `if($scope.message)` condition, returns the confirm message and the data is saved well in localStorage (`saveSomeDataInLocalStorage`function). **All correct**...

But... If enter to `else` condition, the data via `saveSomeDataInLocalStorage`is not saved.

I don't undestand the way of `onbeforeunload` event maybe...

I need to save some data in both cases, returning the confirmation or not.

#### Is there any way to do this?

*Thank you a lot!*

Answer (score 0):

if you return null then no message is shown, so page unload proceeds.
otherwise if you show this message, actually during confirmation process data is saved, so you need to 'freeze' page if you want to save something.
try to always show the message and some status besides it, so user can see data is actually being saved and does not press 'Yes' while process is not completed.

This event cannot be intercepted in any way. It's handler can just return confirmation message or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we return true in the else part?

Comment: yes, but as i said only message returned is shown. in this case you'll have 'true' stringified

Comment: ok got you. I guess this will be the answer then. Makes sense as well

Comment: And there are another way to save data when the tab or window is closed? I don't want to show any confirm message to do this...

Comment: i don't think so. haven't seen something besides this when had similar problem but you can search for it.
in my case the solution was as i described above